# How to access specific db records based on user role?

Tags: java, spring-security

I've a Java Spring Hibernate application integrated with Active Directory for security. I need to allow only users with a specific role to access certain records from a table.
e.g. ROLE1 user can only access records with TYPE=type1
     ROLE2 user can only access records with TYPE=type2
I do not want to create 2 methods to access this data based on the TYPE and secure each method based on user role.
Kindly let me know what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most pragmatic solution is to add a field to the records indicating who's allowed to access them and then include the user's role(s) in the retrieval query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since the user data including roles is already there on Active Directory, will it be a good design to keep that data in the database fields too?

Comment: Never duplicate data like that if you have the choice; they'll get out of sync and cause problems.

Comment: May be i wasn't clear. I was referring to your answer, isn't adding a field to the records indicating who's allowed to access them(roles) not a good approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. May be i wasn't clear. I was referring to your answer, is adding a field to the records indicating who's allowed to access them(roles) a good design? I am now thinking to save the user data in a table every time a user logs in with fields to map it to the 'TYPE' in the example given .Then join the data table with this table to fetch the records based on the field. And clear the user table when the user logs out. Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: This is essentially what the filesystem does, with varying levels of complexity (just owners and groups in traditional Unix-style filesystems, and ACLs in modern systems like ext4 and NTFS). If you don't have any more generalized rule about who's allowed to access a record, then you have to attach access-control information to it.